# project management beyond CVS

Tags: version-control, cvs

CVS is great when you have a simple, self-contained project, but what is the next step up the hierarchy?

I have a lot of individual projects under CVS, but any realistic project has tendrils and dependencies all over the place - libraries used, shared database schemas, common technology with local tweaks.  Managing these project with CVS just isn't in it's domain of
discourse.

I'd like to construct something like a CVS hierarchy view of an arbitrary collection of
files and folders, each of which is part of some other CVS project.

Answer (score 1):

Try github - all the cool kids are using it, and git really does seem to have some improved features over SVN and CVS. Plus github has some nice social features letting you interact with other coders and their projects in nice ways..

Comment: Github is awesome, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion has the concept of "externals", which allows other SVN projects to be checked out at the same time under the same tree

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial's [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepositories) feature is similar to SVN's externals. You can even use SVN repositories as subrepos.